# how to only enable star ratings on WooCommerce products, without requiring comment reviews

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I am looking for code that will enable me to collect Star Reviews on WooCommerce products without requiring users to provide any comments.

This code below gets me almost that far by eliminating the comments box, but WordPress does not allow the saving of the submission. Is something missing from this code?

```
function filter_woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args( $comment_form ) {
    if ( function_exists( 'WC' ) && is_product() ) {
        $comment_form['comment_field'] = '<div class="comment-form-rating"><label for="rating">' . esc_html__( 'Your rating', 'your-theme-text-domain' ) . '</label><select name="rating" id="rating" required>
            <option value="">' . esc_html__( 'Rate&hellip;', 'your-theme-text-domain' ) . '</option>
            <option value="5">' . esc_html__( 'Perfect', 'your-theme-text-domain' ) . '</option>
            <option value="4">' . esc_html__( 'Good', 'your-theme-text-domain' ) . '</option>
            <option value="3">' . esc_html__( 'Average', 'your-theme-text-domain' ) . '</option>
            <option value="2">' . esc_html__( 'Not that bad', 'your-theme-text-domain' ) . '</option>
            <option value="1">' . esc_html__( 'Very poor', 'your-theme-text-domain' ) . '</option>
        </select></div>';

        $comment_form['fields']['author'] = '';
        $comment_form['fields']['email'] = '';
        $comment_form['fields']['url'] = '';
        $comment_form['comment_notes_before'] = '';
        $comment_form['label_submit'] = esc_html__( 'Submit Review', 'your-theme-text-domain' );
        $comment_form['title_reply'] = esc_html__( 'Leave a Review', 'your-theme-text-domain' );
    }
    return $comment_form;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args', 'filter_woocommerce_product_review_comment_form_args' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment `comment_content` field data will be checked for duplicates. As you have removed the field, the data will be empty. So the form submission will always say, there is already one existing. To bypass that, use the below code

```
add_filter('duplicate_comment_id', 'allow_duplicate_comments_with_empty_data', 10, 2);

function allow_duplicate_comments_with_empty_data($dupe_id, $commentdata) {

    // Return false to allow duplicate as the content will be always empty in this case.
    return false;
}
```

You can minimize the above code by using the below code.

```
add_filter('duplicate_comment_id', '__return_false');
```

Add the below code as well to allow empty comments.

```
add_filter('allow_empty_comment', '__return_true');
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. That's awesome.  Can combine your suggested code into my code so so I can see exactly how you are proposing to correct the issue and so that I don't mess it up?

Comment: Just add the line after your code `add_filter('duplicate_comment_id', '__return_false');
`

Comment: Thanks. I tried just adding that one line of code at the end of my code and ran the snippet. I tested the code by selecting the number of stars and when I click "Submit Review" I get the same error message "Error: Please type your comment text."  Somehow Woocommerce won't accept the submission. Any other ways around this?

Comment: @Parham add the code `add_filter('allow_empty_comment', '__return_true');
` along with other one

Comment: You're amazing thank you. I think I misunderstood you originally but since I added both of those single lines of code at the end of my code it now accepts comment submissions with just a star rating. Also it seems that the name and date of the logged in user appears above the star rating. Is it possible to hide that information as well?

Comment: For example, instead of adding the sample CSS code below, is there a way to add PHP code instead?
.woocommerce .star-rating + span.reviewer,

.woocommerce .star-rating + span.woocommerce-review-date {
  display: none;
}

Comment: @Parham Which theme is active?

Comment: I've currently got he ASTRA Theme